# Erro "--no-jetifier" ao iniciar o react-native run-android

Tags: javascript, android-studio, react-native

Eu já tinha feito a instalação do android studio para utilizar o expo, estou tentando emular o android com react-native cli

Ao dar o comando: react-native run-android

aparece o seguinte erro: 
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag. Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers... info JS server already running. error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml' at Object.openSync (fs.js:457:3) at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:359:35) at getLaunchPackageName (C:\Users\Arthu\desktop\projetos\cli\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\getLaunchPackageName.js:161:33) at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Arthu\desktop\projetos\cli\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:163:63) at C:\Users\Arthu\desktop\projetos\cli\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:135:12 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Arthu\desktop\projetos\cli\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)

Answer (score 0):

Fala Arthur. Estava com o mesmo problema.
Porem alguns app de teste funcionaram perfeitamente, e justo na hora que ia por minha ideia em pratica, puf, apareceu esse erro.
Resolvi copiando a pasta BUILD(em : **%seuprojeto%\android\app\Build**) de um projeto (desses que estava testando) para o projeto novo que percebi que não tinha ela no mesmo caminho. Ai pronto. Na primeira tentativa deu um erro devido ao nome do projeto. Na segunda rodou de boa e sem erros.
Não sei se é a melhor pratica mas funcionou pra min.

Comment: Na pasta App do meu projeto não tem uma pasta Build, onde consigo pegar uma? formatei meu pc recentemente

Comment: faz o seguinte. Reinstala somente o react-native cli. No meu percebi também alguns erros. Ai quando reinstalei e criei um projeto novo. Voltou de boa